# Spring batch reading multple file and getting processed count per file

Tags: spring-batch

I am using multiResourceReader to read multiple files and save into a db using single step inbolving reader,writer and processor.

I have implemented StepExecutionListner to get the stats per file however it tells me aggregate read, skip, write count.

I need per file stats. How can I achieve this.

Should i repeat the step per file. I also do not know how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using MultiResourceReader?? is your files have different format or come from different source with different format??

You should use a partitioner to call the step for each file you have in the inbound directory.

Answer (score 0):

Step Execution listener is run after every step. If you read all the files in the same step then it is not possible for you to get the stats of each file.

Comment: How can the step be repeated the step to read consecutive files untill all the files are read?

Comment: can you please share some code so that I can understand it better

Answer (score 0):

One of the goals of `MultiResourceItemReader` is to read items from multiple resources as if they were a single resource. That's why item metrics are the aggregate ones and there is no obvious way to get those metrics per resource.